# Boots up into Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, boot

I am running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 12.04.1, and I when I boot up, I am thrown (Rather violently. :P) a full-sized terminal, instead of my lovely GUI login screen..  So I looked around and tried the "startx" command, which works like a charm.  Only problem is that now, I have no clue how to keep it from booting to the terminal every time,  and boot up into the regular GUI with all my stuff.

I did install some kernel updates the night before, though I restarted my computer twice after I had done so without a problem.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your runlevel. Look in the file **/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf**

You should have the following line for graphical multiuser startup:

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

If you have it set to 1, that means single user mode.
For some distros runlevel 3 means multi user console login.

Read more at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71621/where-is-the-etc-inittab-file-or-how-to-set-the-default-runlevel) and [Debian and Ubuntu Linux Run Levels](http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html).

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!  Of course, my themes are all different and I can't change my launcher icon size, but I'll figure that out.

Comment: Would this work for the opposite? I would love to start without GUI and textmode instead. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo - yes, this should work the other way as well. Read more about runlevels in linux if you want to undersand this better.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. I am going to test it today and inform. :)