# Where is /etc/inittab in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, init.d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the /etc/inittab file or how to set the default runlevel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71621/where-is-the-etc-inittab-file-or-how-to-set-the-default-runlevel)

I have Ubuntu LTS 12.04 32 bit operating system on my laptop. But I could not find /etc/inittab.  Where is it moved? Do we have something new instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing in Debian/Ubuntu.

All major distribution is moving away from SysV init and adopting `systemd`. Ubuntu now uses `upstart`.